# Gap on first animation of slide-from-right with polymer core-animated-pages

Tags: polymer

I'm implementing polymer into a meteor app, and have worked out most of the kinks so far. One thing I'm dealing with is in using slide animations with the core-animated-pages. This is happening with all of them (slide-from-right, slide-from-bottom, slide-up, slide-down).

If I refresh (or first load the page), the first time I run the animation it kind of jerks and then leaves a gap on the side it came from (appearing to over-slide). This is happening on all latest browsers (Chrome/Firefox/Safari).

I'm sliding in a full page (100vh/vw). After I run the animation once, it works fine going forward. It's only the first time the animation is called (after a reload) that this happens. Any ideas? My code looks like:

```
<core-animated-pages fit transitions="slide-from-right">
  <section class="home" fit layout vertical center center-justified>
    {{content}}
  </section>
  <section>
    <div id="page2" fit layout vertical center center-justified slide-from-right>
      {{content}}
    </div>
  </section>
    <div id="page3" fit layout vertical center center-justified slide-from-right>
      {{content}}
    </div>
  </section>
</core-animated-pages>
```

Correction: This seems to be working fine in Firefox, only an issue in Chrome/Safari

Comment: It looks like the `autofocus` on your inputs is causing the jank. Can you verify that's it?