# Meteor transition routed pages via Polymer core-animated-pages

Tags: meteor, polymer, iron-router

I'm building a meteor app with polymer & wanted to include some page transitions.
The two examples I found were: http://www.famehub.co & [Gap on first animation of slide-from-right with polymer core-animated-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266207/gap-on-first-animation-of-slide-from-right-with-polymer-core-animated-pages)

Unfortunately, I don't think these examples use iron-router since they don't register with the URI. (ie there's no "/login" in the address field).

Is there a way to use these transitions while keeping routing? For example, here's a solution if I used famo.us: http://famous-views.meteor.com/features/iron-router

Comment: Did you ever have any success with this, I am also looking to accomplish this

Comment: Nope, there are a few iron router transition packages on atmosphere, but those are not element specific, ie the whole page is gonna fade in, you cant make 1 div slide left while another div slides right. As a workaround, I grabbed the web animations api (same that polymer uses) and animate on render. works great!